Where should I set the environment values so that I can read it in a CustomPresentationDetent?
I want to implement a CustomPresentationDetent that has a different height depending on some external values. For a concrete example, let's say I want my detent to be x points below the maxDetentValue, i.e.
struct MyDetent: CustomPresentationDetent {
    static func height(in context: Context) -> CGFloat? {
        context.maxDetentValue - x
    }
}

Basically, I want to pass this x from the outside.
CustomPresentationDetent.height(in:) is a static method so I cannot write an init that takes those values. Even if I could, I do not even get a chance to call the initialiser, since at the use site, I can only pass the meta type of my custom detent. That is, I must do .custom(MyDetent.self), and not .custom(MyDetent(x: 100)).
Then I thought of passing the values through the environment. The context parameter of height(in:) apparently can be used to access EnvironmentValues by using this dynamic member subscript.
However, the documentation of that subscript says something very confusing:

This uses the environment from where the sheet is shown, not the environment where the presentation modifier is applied.

Hence the question is:
Where exactly to put a .environment modifier so that I modify the environment of "where the sheet is shown"?
I tried adding .environment everywhere I can think of, passing each a different value, but I still see the default value in the height(in:) method. Here is a minimal reproducible example:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SheetPresenter()
            .environment(\.myValue, 1)
    }
}

struct SheetPresenter: View {
    @State private var shown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            shown = true
        }
        .environment(\.myValue, 2)
        .sheet(isPresented: $shown) {
            Text("Sheet")
                .environment(\.myValue, 3)
                .presentationDetents([.custom(MyDetent.self)])
                .environment(\.myValue, 4)
        }
        .environment(\.myValue, 5)
    }
}

struct MyEnvKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Int = 0
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var myValue: Int {
        get { self[MyEnvKey.self] }
        set { self[MyEnvKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct MyDetent: CustomPresentationDetent {
    static func height(in context: Context) -> CGFloat? {
        print(context.myValue)
        return 100
    }
}

On iOS 17.4, simulator, the print(context.myValue) statement always prints 0, the default value.

can you please take a look https://matthewcodes.uk/articles/swiftui-size-to-fit-bottom-sheet/

@OmSanatan That's not what I am trying to do. I'm trying to "pass values to" (in other words, parameterise) custom detents. For a simple example, I want to create a custom detent that is x points below maxDetentHeight. I want this to be parameterised by x. I don't want to create a new CustomPresentationDetent type for every x value I need.

If I understand correctly, you have a view that shows a sheet and the sheet height is dictated by some external value. If so, why don't you just pass the value as a parameter to the view and use it in the sheet's .presentationDetent modifier. I can put together an example if that makes sense to you.

@AndreiG. The view has that value already, but how do I pass that value to a custom detent? You say “use it in the sheet's .presentationDetent”, but there is nowhere to put that value. I cannot do .custom(MyDetent(myValue)), because custom expects a meta type.

You can simply do .presentationDetents([.height(yourvalue)])

@AndreiG. I am implementing my custom detent, not using .height(...). See the concrete example I added in my edit. You cannot do that with the built-in .height detent, can you? Notice how you are able to pass a value to .height(...) - I want my custom detents to take parameters like that, too.

@Sweeper you want to pass value for detent with environment right?

@OmSanatan Yes, since it looks like I can access the environment through the context parameter. I'm just not sure which environment the context is holding. As you can see, I tried to set different environment values in many different places, but I am unable to read any of them from the custom detent.

I am not sure I understand the purpose  of it all. Can you give an example of how and when would the sheet height change, regardless of how the parameter is passed?

@AndreiG. The height doesn't necessarily change at runtime, so let's just assume it doesn't change for simplicity. The question is exactly about "how the parameter is passed", so saying "regardless" to that doesn't make much sense. In the example I gave in the question, I want to create a detent that is x points below maxDetentValue. I don't want to create such a detent type for every value of x I will possibly use. I just want one detent type, and pass the value of x to it, so that I can reuse the detent type.

I have the feeling  you're trying to use environment as a parameter, when it's not really meant for that. I am putting together an example that I think achieves what you need without environment.

@AndreiG. Yeah, that is indeed my ultimate goal, and I would appreciate solutions without using the environment too. That said, I think figuring out which environment the context reads from is a valid question as well.

There is a link in Apple developer forum, but they didn't answer the question ... https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/761515

I am adding another answer that more directly addresses your question and code, but which at the same time shows the problems with your approach.
There were several issues with your code, as follows:

Your environment was set to use values of type Int, whereas a detent needs CGFloat
Regardless, they were never used because MyDetent was returning a constant of 100 of the correct type, CGFloat, instead of returning the actual context.myValue
You were setting the env value in many places, but you were never reading anywhere for actually passing it further to a view
This is a problem since it means you can't manipulate the value
Even if you did read and adjusted the value, it wouldn't change anything, because MyDetent would likely show the defaultValue
To fix this and actually use the adjusted values, you'd need to read it again in the SheetPresenter, BUT use the .height parameter instead, which makes using a custom detent pointless (not that it made sense to use one in the first place).

So the conclusion is that for what you're trying to achieve, you need the .height parameter anyway, and some kind of global value. And unless you have a specific reason for that to exist and be passed via environment, it would make much more sense for it to be a property of an observable object instead.
import SwiftUI

struct SheetCustomDetentRootView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.myValue) private var myValue: CGFloat // <- Here, read the myValue from the environment

    var body: some View {
        SheetPresenterView()
            .environment(\.myValue, myValue)
            // .environment(\.myValue, myValue + 350) // <- Here, uncomment this (and comment out the line above) to pass a custom value via environment
    }
}

struct SheetPresenterView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.myValue) private var myValue: CGFloat // <- Here, read the myValue from the environment
    @State private var shown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            shown = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $shown) {
            Text("My value from environment is: \(Int(myValue))")
                .presentationDetents([.custom(MyDetent.self)])
                // .presentationDetents([.height(myValue)]) // <- Here, uncomment this (and comment out the line above) to use the value passed via environment
        }
    }
}

struct MyEnvKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 100
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var myValue: CGFloat {
        get { self[MyEnvKey.self] }
        set { self[MyEnvKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct MyDetent: CustomPresentationDetent {
    static func height(in context: Context) -> CGFloat? {
        print(context.myValue)
        return context.myValue
    }
}

#Preview {
    SheetCustomDetentRootView()
}


So at the end of the day you are still telling me to use .height? That isn't what this is about. The context parameter in a custom detent supposedly has access to the environment using the dynamic member subscript. I am not asking about how to do something, but which environment is the context accessing. As the documentation says, it is "the environment from where the sheet is shown", and I want to know where that is.

You mentioned "because MyDetent would likely show the defaultValue", and this is exactly what I am observing as you can see in the code in the question. Can you elaborate on why that is the case instead of just asserting it?

I think it's important to establish whether your intention is to adjust the sheet height based on external (preset) values or based on the context. AFAIK, context usually refers to the context of the sheet, that is whether the sheet appears on a small screen or a larger screen (like an iPad) or maybe in a vertical or landscape orientation. These varying heights are what make up the "context". As such, you'd access the available height by reading the context's maxDetentValue: context.maxDetentValue and then adjust the sheet size relative to the available height. Is that your goal?

So, if you want a sheet that is always 50 points below the half point of the available height, you'd use a custom detent, basically a preset, because the 50 points value doesn't change. This allows for the preset/detent to be centrally defined and applied to any sheet in any view. Similarly, if you want to also have sheets at specific heights, like 100, 200, 300, you can create custom detents that return these fixed values. But, if you want to dynamically control the "50 points" value, even if it's relative to the context, then you'd have to use .height or .fraction to set the sheet size.

"because MyDetent would likely show the defaultValue" - the environment value is a constant and I don't see any states or bindings or any other mechanism that would cause the UI/sheet to react to changes in that value. After spending some more time trying to get it to work, I couldn't, and that's precisely the unnecessary environment values gymnastics I mentioned I wanted to avoid, especially when there is a much simpler way, given your use case. I found this article that may offer you more insight.

Because I can't wrap my mind around the need for a custom detent or environment values gymnastics, here's a simpler example that uses:

An observable class with a singleton to hold the max detent value
A view that accepts optional parameters for adjusting the sheet height relative to the max detent value
An internal state that allows further control if needed over the adjustment value

As such, you can:

Define a general max detent value in the singleton class
Update the max detent value as needed from anywhere (shown here as the textfield and stepper input of SomeTopView() )
Call the view that has the sheet with an adjustment value or without one (in which case the sheet will have the max detent value height)
Adjust the sheet height internally, if needed, in the same view as the sheet
Lose less hair due to not having to worry about environment values or custom detents.

import SwiftUI

struct SheetDetentView: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var settings = SomeObserverClass.settings
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            SomeTopView()
                .background(.background.secondary)
                .frame(height: 100)
            
            SheetPresenter(adjustHeight: 20) //or simply SheetPresenter() if no adjustment needed
        }
    }
}

struct SomeTopView: View {
    
    //Bindings
    @Bindable private var settings = SomeObserverClass.settings
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section("Top View"){
                HStack {
                    Text("Set max height")
                        .fixedSize()
                    TextField("Height", value: $settings.maxDetentValue, formatter: NumberFormatter() )
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .background(.background.secondary)
                    Stepper("", value: $settings.maxDetentValue, in: 100...450, step: 50)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct SheetPresenter: View {

    //Parameters
    var adjustHeight: CGFloat? = 0
    
    //Bindings
    @Bindable private var settings = SomeObserverClass.settings

    //State values
    @State private var adjustValue: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var shown = true
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section("Bottom Sheet Presenter View") {
                
                Text("Max height is: \(settings.maxDetentValue, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)) )")
                
                //Inputs
                HStack {
                    Text("Adjust height")
                        .fixedSize()
                    TextField("Height", value: $adjustValue, formatter: NumberFormatter() )
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .background(.background.secondary)
                    Stepper("", value: $adjustValue, in: 0...settings.maxDetentValue, step: 10)
                }
                
                Button("Toggle Sheet") {
                    shown.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $shown) {
                    let maxHeight = settings.maxDetentValue
                    let adjustedHeight = maxHeight - adjustValue
                    
                    Text("Adjust parameter is: \(adjustValue, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)) )")
                    .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    
                    Text("Adjusted height is: \(adjustedHeight, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)) )")
                    
                    Text("(\(Int(adjustValue)) below max detent value of \(Int(maxHeight)) )")
                        .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                        .padding(.top)

                        .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                        .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
                        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
                        .presentationDetents([.height(adjustedHeight), .large])
                        
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            //if a parameter is passed to the view, set the state value to the parameter value
            if let value = adjustHeight {
                adjustValue = value
            }
        }
    }
}


@Observable
class SomeObserverClass {
    
    var maxDetentValue: CGFloat = 350
    
    static let settings = SomeObserverClass() //singleton
    
    private init() {}
}

#Preview {
    SheetDetentView()
}

If you run the code above, you'll get the following, which allows you to play around with the values and notice how sheet height changes thanks to the observable singleton:


If I understand correctly, you seem to have hardcoded 350 as the initial max detent value? But what I want is the maxDetentValue that one gets from the context parameter? Or is there a way to get that outside of a CustomPresentationDetent?

I just added a screenshot. Try running the code to see it in action. The observable class holds the maxDetentValue that I arbitrarily set to 350, but you can update it from anywhere at anytime, so in a way it's like an environment value. You can access it from any view or any function outside a view. I am not sure why we're still talking about custom detents, the whole point is that they're not needed for your purposes, from what I understand. Custom detents are for when you need to create preset sizes of sheet heights, which doesn't seem to be the case.

You can, technically, create an environment key and then pass the maxDetentValue  through the environment, usually in the app root, or to a specific view, but why do that, when you can have global/centralized maxDetentValue in a singleton class that can be read and updated from anywhere?  To clarify, with this setup, you can read the maxDetentValue with SomeObservableClass.settings.maxDetentValue and you can set it the same way: SomeObservableClass.settings.maxDetentValue = 100.
